# Get fixed size combinations of a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, combinations, slice, python-itertools

I am looking for modified version of itertools.product(*a). This command returns combinations by selecting elements from each list but I need to restrict size.

Suppose,

```
mylist = [[6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 9], [2, 1, 4]]

output: (6, 3), (6, 2),....(3, 2)... when size is 2
```

Number of lists and size are not fixed. I need something that can be dynamic enough.

Comment: ```[list(combinations(i,2)) for i in mylist]```?

Comment: @Sujay this command is returning [[(6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)], [(3, 5), (3, 9), (5, 9)], [(2, 1), (2, 4), (1, 4)]] i.e. creating combinations within the list not across multiple lists.

Comment: Check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain

mylist=[[6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 9], [2, 1]]
size = 2

results = chain.from_iterable(product(*t) for t in combinations(mylist, size))
print(list(results))
```

Comment: it works, Thanks.. but isn't the performance issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
l=[[6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 9], [2, 1, 4]]
x=list(combinations(chain.from_iterable(l),2))
print(x)
```

Comment: Still getting combinations from each lists i.e. (6,7),(6,8)... can we remove them ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import itertools

size = 2
mylist = [[6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 9], [2, 1, 4]]

res = []
for x in list(itertools.product(*mylist)):
    res += itertools.combinations(x, size)
print(set(res))
```